# Distinguish time for fixtures generation and actual test

Tags: symfony, testing, doctrine-orm, phpunit, fixtures

I am working on Symfony2 with Doctrine2.

Is there any way to measure the time it takes to generate the fixtures, and the actual time it takes to phpunit to execute my test ?

Comment: simply use the [Symfony Stopwatch](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/stopwatch.html)

Comment: Thanks, that totally does the job.

Comment: But be aware that using the Symfony Profiler during tests can slow down your Test Execution pretty much. So just use to optimize stuff but not for "standard test runs".

Comment: Of course, I just wanted to know which part was longer and by how much. I am trying to optimize my functionnals tests.